# Windows Phone 7.1 add shadows for text in a text block

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7.1, shadow, textblock

I am trying to add shadows for text in the text block. I am using Windows phone 7.1

```
<TextBlock   Text="Shadow Text"   Foreground="Teal"> 
 <TextBlock.Effect>
   <DropShadowEffect  ShadowDepth="4"   Direction="330"  Color="Black"  Opacity="0.5" BlurRadius="4"/>  
  </TextBlock.Effect>
</TextBlock>
```

but TextBlock.Effect does not work on my visual studio 2010.
is that a framework problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,200,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="60" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"  Text="Your Text" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="/SlXnaApp1;component/Font/Fonts.zip#Digital tech"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="-2,200,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="60" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"  Text="Your Text" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="/SlXnaApp1;component/Font/Fonts.zip#Digital tech"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,202,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="60" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"  Text="Your Text" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="/SlXnaApp1;component/Font/Fonts.zip#Digital tech"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,198,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="60" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"  Text="Your Text" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="/SlXnaApp1;component/Font/Fonts.zip#Digital tech"/>

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,200,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="60" Foreground="#FFE01B90" FontWeight="Bold"  Text="Your Text" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="/SlXnaApp1;component/Font/Fonts.zip#Digital tech"/>
```

First four textblock for shadow and last textblock for show your text.

Answer (score 0):

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect(v=vs.95).aspx) there is no support for DropShadowEffect in Windows Phone.

Comment: what should i do then

Comment: @mkpchiran shadows are not welcome in Windows Phone. However you can use another TextBlock with same text as Shadow.